# Styling spinner Android

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

[image]

[image]

I find the spinner to be very frustrating to use programmatically and to style

I'd like to change the styling from the first picture (where the arrow is pointing down in the center) to the second picture (where the arrow is angled and it's located in the bottom right).

How do I do this?

// styling for spinner

```
    <style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerMode">dialog</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0.05dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: have you had a chance to implement my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Widget.Holo.Spinner as your parent style for the spinner:

```
<style name="spinner_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
     <!-- YOUR STYLE HERE -->
</style>
```